# how a table data gets loaded into a dataframe in databricks? row by row or bulk?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, pyspark

I am new to databricks notebooks and dataframes. I have a requirement to load few columns(out of many) in a table of around 14million records into a dataframe. once the table is loaded, I need to create a new column based on values present in two columns.

I want to write the logic for the new column along with the select command while loading the table into dataframe.
Ex:

```
df =  spark.read.table(tableName)
          .select(columnsList)
          .withColumn('newColumnName', 'logic')
```

will it have any performance impact? is it better to first load the table for the few columns into the df and then perform the column manipulation on the loaded df?

does the table data gets loaded all at once or row by row into the df? if row by row, then by including column manipulation logic while reading the table, am I causing any performance degradation?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the underlying format of the table - is it backed by Parquet or Delta, or it's an interface to the actual database, etc.  In general, Spark is trying to read only necessary data, and if, for example, Parquet is used (or Delta), then it's easier because it's column-oriented file format, so data for each column is placed together.

Regarding the question on the reading - Spark is lazy by default, so even if you put `df = spark.read.table(....)` as separate variable, then add `.select`, and then add `.withColumn`, it won't do anything until you call some action, for example `.count`, or write your results. Until that time, Spark will just check that table exists, your operations are correct, etc.  You can always call `.explain` on the resulting dataframe to see how Spark will perform operations.

P.S. I recommend to grab a free copy of the [Learning Spark, 2ed](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly) that is provided by Databricks - it will provide you a foundation for development of the code for Spark/Databricks